# edit file using vi editor in java

Tags: java, vi

I'm writing a program where I need to telnet into a remote machine, access a file and edit it. 
I am able to do the telnet part. 
This gives me access to the OutputStream and InputStream of that system. I can send commands and open up the file using a vi editor. I am also able to read the contents of the file

```
DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(telnet.getInputStream());
data.readLine().
```

But I am unable to write to this file or edit it. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Rather than use vi, can you express what you need to do in terms of a `sed` script? That will eliminate the need to navigate around the screen.

Comment: does the user in the remote machine have the permission to write into the file?

Comment: Which api are you using for telnet? I suspect you cannot use `vi` because it is a **visual** command and interacts with the device keyboard, not `stdin`/`stdout`. How are the modifications provided?

Comment: I'm using apache-commons.net API. I am able to vi and read the contents ..but I can't write into it. I have access to write to it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are running into line-editing issues on the remote system.  I think that using `sed` (as @Jim Garrison mentioned) or using the `ed` editor which is line based would work instead of the key based editor like vi or emacs.

Here's a quick example of how to use ed to edit the file named "file".  `man ed` should show the various features.

```
> ed file
file: No such file or directory
i
hello there
.
1
hello there
a
and now append a line
.
1,$n
1       hello there
2       and now append a line
w
34
q

> cat file
hello there
and now append a line
```